# Sublime text 2, ctrl+d not working as expected

Tags: linux, sublimetext2

It seems that 'quick add next' and 'expand selection to word' are both mapped to the same key binding.

I am not sure how to override/change the 'expand selection to word' because I cannot find the current key binding for both actions.

Does anyone know what the two actions are called?

Just to clarify, let's say I have the following block of code

```
this.GRID_TOP = 10;
this.GRID_SPACING = 10;
this.GRID_HEIGHT = 10;
this.GRID_WIDTH = 10;
```

I want to select the 'GRID' string on each line. I could use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> but that's overkill. I want to select 'GRID' then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to select the subsequent matches. My problem is that it works once (selects first two) but then expands both cursors to the end of their words. Since the selections are now different, I cannot 'quick add next'.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem on Windows 7—selecting `GRID` in its entirety and hitting `Ctrl+D` three times selects all instances of `GRID`, nothing more. Have you added any keybindings to `Preferences -> Key Bindings – User`, or adjusted any related settings in `Preferences -> Settings – User`? Also, does the same problem happen when using `Find -> Quick Add Next` instead of `Ctrl+D`? Are there any external packages that could be interfering?

Answer (score 10):

## Bug conditions and effect

This seems to be a bug, or at least an unintuitive behaviour that only happens when the search bar is opened (after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, etc.) AND you selected a word part that is not already the string in the Find field (e.g. you searched for TOP before, and then you selected GRID).

The bug seems to be due to the specific behavior of `find_under_expand` while searching. In search mode, it will fill the Find field with the whole word under the caret on the first call, then starts finding and adding more occurrences to the selection. But it has some inconsistencies. For instance, if you click on different words one after the other, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> after each click, and it will always fill the Find field with the word, but will alternatively not highlight the word and highlight it.

When you select a sub-word, it gets worse and only the next sub-word gets highlighted the first time you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. The following times, you get a mix of *fill Find field*, *cursor goes to end of word* and *extend selection* (a behavior that made sense on a single and complete word) which results in the selection of the first two words, with the second word (`GRID_SPACING`) filling the Find field.

## Workaround

### Solution 1

Close the search bar with <kbd>esc</kbd> and *then* use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> / `Find > Quick Add Next` repeatedly. Note that the selection won't be highlighted as searched strings (yellow in the default theme), but only as normal selection highlight (gray in the default theme).

### Solution 2

If, after your first <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you realized that your search bar was opened (and the Find field did not previously contain your target sub-word), it is not too late. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> / `Edit > Undo Selection > Soft Undo` to go back to the original sub-word selected. From here, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> repeatedly. With the Find field containing the target sub-word, selection will behave as expected.

Comment: This came up in the [Late Answers Review Queue](/review/late-answers/stats), and I was honestly rather shocked to find that it _wasn't an audit_. Good work!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it looks much better. I'll remember to use the <kbd> tag next time!

Answer (score 5):

Go to *Preferences > Key Bindings - User*

put following lines and save the file:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "find_under_expand_skip" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+d"], "command": "dpaste"}
```

It works for me. I've got installed DPaste package. That is why I had to overwrite its shortcut with the last line. Dpaste comes by default with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Hope it help